# Simplify one line if statement

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a one liner `if` statement that looks like this:

```
var = var if var < 1. else 1.
```

The first part `var = var` looks a bit ugly and I'd bet there's a more pythonic way to say this.

Comment: Not ugly to me, makes perfect readable sense. This assignment syntax is pretty pythonic.

Comment: That **is** actually the pythonic way of doing it.

Comment: How about flipping it? `var = 1 if var > 1. else var`

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/ternary-conditional-operator-in-python, they arrive at the same conclusion.

Comment: What is "1."? Is it just me or is there a dot after the 1?

Comment: @Smac89 the dot indicates that this is a float, not an integer.

Comment: @ViktorKerkez I don't think this syntax is so good - it's like `var = var` (pause) oh, but only `if var < 1. else 1.`

Comment: I might prefer `1.0` here just to avoid confusion. I, too, stared for a second before coffee kicked in and told me that's a decimal point, not punctuation.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The following is *39%* shorter and in my opinion is simpler and more pythonic than other answers. *But* we should note  that sometimes people get it wrong thinking that 1 is a lower bound being confused by `min` function when actually 1 is an upper bound for `var`.

```
var = min(var, 1.0)
```

Comment: Despite your doubts, I think your answer *is* better and more simple than the asker's original code. Sure, neither is exactly complicated, but this is marginally easier for my brain to parse than the ternary expression is - I'd certainly rather see this one in the middle of some dense, difficult code than the original.

Comment: I think it is quite pythonic - it clearly states intent without having to look through extra logic.

Comment: The OP is comparing to `1.`, not `1`. This can potentially make a difference depending on the type of `var`.

Comment: +1, except that most readers will involuntary tend to associate the word `min` with a lower bound for `var`, when the real meaning is just the opposite. Seen this too many times. For readability, I prefer an if-based version even if slightly longer, and I wish language designers had promoted alternative names for `min` and `max`.  Again, there is no need to make things potentially confusing if there is little or no gain.

Comment: @MarioRossi, agree with you, that's why I added a small disclaimer. As my final decision I would say this is arguably more pythonic than other answers but harder to understand sometimes. Anyway, this is my personal choice and I would use it myself.

Comment: @sasha.sochka  Yes, a lot about personal preference here.  This's why my +1 from the beginning (I couldn't find an option "+0.9999999999" :) ).

Answer (score 9):

```
if var >= 1.:
    var = 1
```

or if you like one liners

```
if var >= 1.: var = 1
```

Comment: This is the best approach in my opinion, +1.

Comment: +1 It's also more readable by the occassional person more used to another programming language. I know, he/she will most probably get lost at other points of the program, but why contribute to confusion when there is no gain but "pythonicity"?

Answer (score 5):

Doesn't eliminate the `var = var` but it's shorter and one could argue, more pythonic:

```
var = min(var, 1.0)
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this way would be shorter

```
var = min(var, 1.0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the equivalence of True=1 and False=0 to index into a 2-tuple of the possible values:

```
var = (1,var)[var < 1.]
```

If `var < 1.`, then this evalutes to True, which is equivalent to 1. This simplifies to:

```
var = (1,var)[1]
```

Or

```
var = var
```

if not `var < 1.`, this evaluates to False, which is equivalent to 0, giving:

```
var = (1,var)[0]
```

or

```
var = 1
```

So this one-liner:

```
var = (1,var)[var < 1.]
```

is equivalent to:

```
if var < 1.:
    var = var
else:
    var = 1
```

Comment: O.O I'm not sure I even understand this line.

Comment: Interesting construction, but I don't consider relying on `False = 0, True = 1` very pythonic...

Comment: +1  For originality and applicability in other cases.  Personally, I wouldn't use it because of the reasons exposed by @Gabriel.

Comment: @Tobias Keinzler  IMHO, the relationship is completely pythonic (in the same way as it is an integral part of C).  Otherwise, the original language design would have included a separate Boolean type explicitly.

Comment: @MarioRossi It is done like it is done, and yet `None` is also interpreted as `False`, so what if at some point `False = None`. And `True = not False` could also be `2`. I'm just saying that the association of Booleans and integers is arbitrary and _not_ pythonic at all but rather backwards-compatibility with C

Comment: @Tobias Keinzler  Right, especially when `None` is equivalent to C's `null` and C's `null` also evaluates to `False`.  I'm new to Python and realizing that "Pythonic" doesn't mean "supported by the Python language" but "preferred by the Python community/language spirit".  In that case, I'm extremely glad these Boolean equivalencies / implicit conversions / definition of Python's  boolean operators (I don't know how to exactly say it) are not considered "Pythonic".

Comment: @MarioRossi - not original at all, this is just "old school" Python from before there was a ternary expression, used as a safer alternative to `condition and true_value or false_value`, see my comments on tdelaney's answer. And also this version *is* guaranteed by the Python language spec, which defines True and False to be equivalent to 1 and 0. But it is inferior to today's ternary expression in that `true_var if condition else false_var` will short-circuit, which is very helpful when `false_var` is implemented using an expensive function, such as a database retrieval.